# getContextPath using servlet

Tags: servlets

Context path in jboss-web.xml is mentioned as `/Test`, but my war file name is `Test-0.0.1`.
I need this war file name using `HttpServlet`. Please tell me the function name.
i tried `getContextPath()`, but it returns Test.
Thanks

Answer (score 42):

Here is the list of functions that are available, along with a graphic showing how they are related.  in this example, the war file name is usually in the "context path" piece, in this case "myapp".  This is a folder create by TomCat from the WAR file, and while based on the WAR file name, it does not need to be the same.  Look for a folder with a name like "Test".

[image]

(From [HttpServletRequest Path Decoding](https://agiletribe.purplehillsbooks.com/2016/02/23/httpservletrequest-path-decoding/))

Comment: That diagram is excellent, and highlights the inadequacy of the official Javadoc for HttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 7):

If the WAR is expanded, you could use [`ServletContext.getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) in combination with [`File.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) to obtain the expanded folder name. This will be the same as the WAR file name.

```
String name = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")).getName();
```

Comment: @BaluC but getRealPath() might give the value of content root which will be context root.  WAR file name on the other hand can different from the context root right?

Answer (score 4):

`ServletContext.getContextPath()` is the way to get the context path. It can differ from the war-file name, but I can't think of a reason you may need the war file name.

Answer (score 1):

From the Servlet API there is no way to access the war file name. The war file name is different from the context root. And , even the `ServletContext.getRealPath()` is the extract location of the war file, which can be different.