# get the war file name in jboss

Tags: servlets, jboss

How can I get the deployed war file name inside jboss. For example, when I am inside a servlet and I want to know the which war file name that I am in.

Thanks,

Son Nguyen

Comment: There may be another way to achieve what you are trying to do. So, what are you trying to do?

Comment: There are some naming convention in my company that stores configuration based on the deployed war file name. I just want to get it programmatically instead of setting it.

Comment: Very often, the war file name is the same as the web applications context path (abc.war => /abc/...). You can get that from ServletContext. Would that work in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String warName = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")).getName();
```

Comment: [Deja vu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417949/getcontextpath-using-servlet/3896115#3896115) :)

Comment: @BalusC - haha, yes.. in fact it's more interesting - I needed that piece of code the other day for a strange usecase (had to browse an unextracted war), so I copied it from your answer. Then I copied it here from my code :D